# Correcting my Regular Expression [^-]*[^-]

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am provided a field with a hyphens wrapping the data. How ever, there are times when the data includes a hyphen.
Data example:

```
-4869--149x-1--2925--2927--1520x-1--2459--3400--3403--3404--3410x14--3412--1645--3413--3406x14--3408x14--3415--204x-4--1507x-40--3460x14--4527x-1--3973x-1--1599x-1-
```

The second item `-149x-1-` is splitting at the hyphen before the 1. This happens on all x-1 items.

I am looking to correct my regex to skip over the x- and go to the next hyphen.

Comment: You probably want `Regex.Split(text, "-{2,}")`. Or `Regex.Matches(text, "\w+(?:-\d+\b)?")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What a cludgy date format. It looks like each item in your data stream has both a leading and a trailing hyphen to delimit it. So, for all practical purposes, every item in the data stream is separated from the next by two hyphens ('--'), with the first and last items having a single hyphen preceding, or following it, respectively.

Assuming that that is the case, the easiest method of parsing this would be to

- remove the leading and trailing hyphen from the entire string, then
- split it on `--`

So you would have code something like:

```
"-v-1--v-2--v-3--v-4-"
.Trim("-")
.Split(
  new[]{"--"} , // need to do it this way because of overload restrictions
  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries
) ;
```

which should yield the array `[ "v-1", "v-2", "v-3", "v-4" ]`.

[Edited to note: If the individual data elements in this string may start with or end with a hyphen, your are probably SOL.]

Comment: It is a very cludgy data format, but unfortunately I am stuck with it (outside vendor).  I am much closer to what I need.   Thank you!

Comment: Little extra searching has completed the parsing of the cludgy data line. 'newSetItems = inSetItems.Trim("-")
        MainArray = newSetItems.Split(New String() {"--"}'  It is now placing the correct values in the array.  Again, thank you!

Comment: Be wary of `.Split("--")` - it will silently use only the first character of the string "--". There are overloads of [String.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netcore-3.1) which *do* use a string.

Comment: @AndrewMorton: Good catch. I'm not near my Windows dev box right now (thanks COVID-19!). And the overloads on that one are annoying due to implicit conversion from string to `char[]`. But that wouldn't use just the first character. It will split on _any_ character in the `char[]`. So, `someStringVar.Split("abc")` will use any of `a`, `'b`, or `c` as the field delimeter on which to split.